# TYPO3 Is there a way to change the Header Date format?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am using TYPO3 7.2. Using the standard template engine is it possible to change the format of the header date in a content element?

This breaks down to 2 questions:

1) Can you make the header date display the name of the month? (eg. March 14)

2) In the back end the date selected in the field is shown as dd/mm/yy, but on the actual site it is displayed as mm/dd/yy. How do I fix this so I get dd/mm/yy order on the published site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your TypoScript template:

```
lib.stdheader.5.strftime = %B %d
```

More formats by: [PHP's strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Comment: How do I wrap it? lib.stdheader.5.strftime =  <div class="month">%B</div><div class="day">%d</div> (This ends up outside the csc-header-date wrap)

Comment: No, this is not the way, TypoScript works. Basically, if you want to wrap something, you have to use a stdWrap functionality for it. So if you want to have a wrap around it, you have to set something like lib.stdheader.5.wrap = <div>|</div> (also see https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6/typo3/sysext/css_styled_content/static/setup.txt#L215).

You will see that this will wrap the whole date. To achieve your desired result, you have to split the whole thing in 2 parts. But this is quite complex and the space of this comment is limited. Basically, you have to work with a COA element.

Answer (score 0):

For TYPO3 version 8.7 I had to override `TYPO3.CMS/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials/Header/Date.html`. 
Set the path in the typoscript to the new partials with `lib.contentElement.partialRootPaths.30 = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Partials/` and I guess `tt_content.header = < lib.contentElement` is needed too to make the configuration relevant to the header.

The path to the new partial would then be `my_extension/Resources/Private/Partials/Header/Date.html`